# List with fonts on the computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

So I have a div with text in it that changes when you select a different font in the select list that I made.
At the moment the list is pretty limited because I have to add fonts by myself.

Is there any way to add all the fonts installed on the users computer to the list with a code instead of having to add them all by myself?

**HTML**

```
<div id="generate">
       Change the text! 
</div>

<select id="box" onchange="font();">
    <option id="PIC" value="Kies een font">Kies een font.</option>
    <option id="TNR" value="TimesNewRoman">Times New Roman</option>
    <option id="GRG" value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option id="PLT" value="PalatinoLinotype">Palatino Linotype</option>
    <option id="ARL" value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option id="CMS" value="ComicSans">Comic Sans</option>
    <option id="IMP" value="Impact">Impact</option>
    <option id="TMS" value="TrebuchetMS">Trebuchet MS</option>
    <option id="TSB" value="TheSansBlack">The Sans Black Plain</option>
</select><br />
```

**Javascript**

```
 function font() {
        var sf = document.getElementById('box').value;
        var generate = document.getElementById('generate');

        switch(sf){
            case 'TimesNewRoman': 
                generate.style.fontFamily = ('Times New Roman')
                break;
            case 'Georgia': 
                generate.style.fontFamily = ('Georgia')
                break;
            case 'PalatinoLinotype': 
                generate.style.fontFamily = ('Palatino Linotype')
                break;
            case 'Arial': 
                generate.style.fontFamily = ('Arial')
                break;
            case 'ComicSans': 
                generate.style.fontFamily = ('Comic Sans MS')
                break;
            case 'Impact': 
                generate.style.fontFamily = ('Impact')
                break;
            case 'TrebuchetMS': 
                generate.style.fontFamily = ('Trebuchet MS')
                break;
            default: generate.style.fontFamily = ('')
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate the installed fonts using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597682/how-to-iterate-the-installed-fonts-using-javascript)

Comment: I was going to say no, but it's answered in the above link :)

Comment: Not with javascript alone, but quite easy with js + flash, see e.g. http://hasseg.org/blog/post/526/getting-a-list-of-installed-fonts-with-flash-and-javascript/

Comment: This ability has been demonstrated as a security flaw. The idea is that if you can list  fonts installed on a computer, it can give you insights into what software is installed, and also give you an additional way of tracking the user; combine the font list with other details and it becomes possible to uniquely identify a user even if they've disabled normal tracking methods like cookies for example. I'm sure your intention is not to do this, but it's worth knowing about anyway because if it's considered a security flaw, it may end up being blocked by the browser makers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check availability of particular font http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

One thing you can do is create own list and compare it's availability as mentioned in link above and show only fonts which are available on client system.