# How to find suitable fonts that are installed on a user's machine?

Tags: html, web, fonts, font-family

I am making an email template and I'm trying to find the right fonts for it.

My problem is that I cannot use @font-face AT ALL (it's stripped out using sendgrid).  and thus I need the fonts to be installed on the machine of the user and accessible by font-family without using @font-face.

How would I find suitable fonts to use? Also; I cant use Javascript because some email clients don't allow that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate the installed fonts using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597682/how-to-iterate-the-installed-fonts-using-javascript)

Comment: Tl;Dr you can't really

Comment: http://www.cssfontstack.com/

Comment: Liam it's not duplicate, you shouldn't use javascript in email clients and there are much longer posts on this site so pls.

Comment: Thanks @Turnip that's pretty much what I need! But it has very little fonts to choose from.

Comment: That's because there are very few fonts that are shared across OSs. If they aren't on the list - don't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see "how many machines have them installed." - this is simply impossible & not even the right approach.

The right approach(**Safe web fonts**) would be to use `@font-face` fetching fonts from users **local machine**(Windows/MAC pre-installed) using the `local()` to fetch from the users pre-installed fonts.

```
font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: local('Verdana');
    src: local('Arial');
    src: local(sans-serif);
    //result would be - font-family: 'Verdana', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
```

The location in any Windows users machine from where the fonts are being pulled is:

```
C:\Windows\Fonts
```

The location in any MAC users machine from where the fonts are being pulled is:

```
/Library/Fonts/
```

You could see all other pre-installed fonts here as well.

You can check from these, all the common fonts that are pre-installed on Windows & MAC

http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html

http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html

**UPDATED**

If sendgrid is stripping all your embedded styles then use inline styles instead on your elements/body.

```
<body style="font-family: 'myFont'; src: local('Verdana');">...</body>
```

There are also some good **inliner** out there that will convert your embedded CSS to inline CSS.

Zurb email inliner - http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html

Comment: @font-face is stripped out of the code in sendgrid. Can I use local in font-family too?

Comment: @font-face is used to just define a font, without defining how can you use it. If not why even create a font-face, why not use say, `font-family: cursive;` directly on your body. This will work too. Whats stopping you from this ?

Comment: The font itself is really important because I have a design to follow along with.

Comment: If the sendgrid is stripping your styles then why not use them "inline" on your elements/body. `<body style="font-family: 'myFont'; src: local('Verdana');">...</body>` Inline styles will not be stripped :)

Comment: Mmm, yeah! :) The bottom 2 links were the answer to my question btw, thanks!

Comment: Cool, given some more links just in case, inliner - to convert all your embedded CSS to inline. You can accept so it can help others as well. Cheers